# How to use jsonschema in order to prevent sql injection?

Tags: node.js, json, validation, sql-injection, jsonschema

In my node.js serverless app (aws-lambda function), I got input validation using jsonschema.

I want to have the ability to avoid making SQL injection to my server side code.

Is there any option to use jsonschema to validate such cases ?

Alternatively, which minimal regex could help us check this case ?

Comment: I would think SQL injection protection would happen at the database layer not the json layer.

Comment: the idea is to prevent such calls in the first layer and return error to client

Comment: jsonschema is just a modeling spec. I donj't see how yu would act on any of the data using it.

Comment: jsonschema makes validation to json data by given json structure to validate each field by set of rules

Answer (score 3):

I will state unequivocally that validating a JSON document with jsonschema has nothing to do with SQL injection defense.

In other words, a JSON document can pass jsonschema validation but still present a SQL injection risk.

Here's a valid JSON document:

```
{
  "film": "Singin' in the Rain",
  "year": 1952
}
```

This would pass a jsonschema that requires the keys "film" and "year" in the object.

But it's unsafe to use in an SQL expression, because of the apostrophe character in "Singin' in the Rain".

Suppose you were to use this JSON content unsafely, by interpolating it directly into an SQL query string:

```
// UNSAFE!
var sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO Films SET attributes = '${jsonDocument}'`
```

This will result in imbalanced quotes, and at best this causes an SQL syntax error when you execute the query.

```
INSERT INTO Films SET attributes = '{ "film": "Singin' in the Rain, "year": 1952 }'
                                                     ^ error
```

There might be an opportunity for attackers to exploit it, but it's bad enough that it results in syntax errors.

The proper solution to most SQL injection problems is to **use query parameters.** Keep the javascript variables separate from the SQL query string. Instead, pass variables as parameters.

```
// SAFE!
var sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO Films SET attributes = ?`

db.query(sqlQuery, [jsonDocument]).then(...);
```